# Curlpp and PUT request

Tags: put, curlpp

How to send PUT request using curlpp library? I found out how to send http POST (example below) or GET request, but nothing for PUT request.

```cpp
curlpp::Cleanup cleaner;
curlpp::Easy request;
    
request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::Url(url));
curlpp::types::WriteFunctionFunctor functor(WriteMemoryCallback);
curlpp::options::WriteFunction *test = new curlpp::options::WriteFunction(functor);
request.setOpt(test);
    
std::list<std::string> header;
header.push_back("Content-Type: application/json");
    
request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::HttpHeader(header));
request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::PostFields(message));
request.perform();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same question and found the solution when looking for the way to do it using libcurl, see [Send string in PUT request with libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569826/send-string-in-put-request-with-libcurl).

You need to specify the PUT method with

```
request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::CustomRequest{"PUT"});
```

the other required options are the same as with to the POST method.