# How to use libcurl with this request and get json server answer c++?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I have some requests and i want to usen them in libcurl. But i dont know how to do this
So whot should i do implemete this in code like "curl.get(dsds) curl.header("", "")"

```
curl "https://pterodactyl.file.properties/api/client/account" \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer apikey' \
  -X GET \

curl "https://pterodactyl.file.properties/api/client/account/email" \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer apikey' \
  -X PUT \
  -d '{
  "email": "example@xample.com",
  "password": "Password"
}' 

curl "https://pterodactyl.file.properties/api/client/account/api-keys" \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer apikey' \
  -X POST \
  -d '{
  "description": "Restricted IPs",
  "allowed_ips": ["127.0.0.1", "192.168.0.1"]
}' 

curl "https://pterodactyl.file.properties/api/client/account/api-keys/NWKMYMT2Mrav0Iq2" \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer apikey' \
  -X DELETE \
```

Comment: Create a program that either compiles libcurl or links against it, then read through the documentation and samples to learn how to make those requests. They aren't difficult, but if you run into issues you can ask those specific questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic function for downloading something from web is

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include<curl/curl.h>
static size_t WriteCallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}
std::string curlDownload(std::string link){
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string readBuffer;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, link.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "myUserName"); //auth for userName
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "Password"); //auth for password
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return readBuffer;
}
int main() {

    std::string myLink = "https://pterodactyl.file.properties/api/client/account";
    std::cout << curlDownload(myLink) << std::endl; //this will print your request for authorization

    return 0;
}
```

In order to put stuff you will need something like this, with your own data ofcourse

```cpp
curl = curl_easy_init();

if (curl) {
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, client_id_header);
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers); 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, request_url);  
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT"); /* !!! */

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_struct); /* data goes here */

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_slist_free_all(headers);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

More about put [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569826/send-string-in-put-request-with-libcurl) and [here](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/httpput.html)

More about CURLOPT [here](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html)
This will return `std::string` with given output, your json for example. Then you need to parse it.

In order to install libcurl for windows, you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861300/how-do-you-properly-install-libcurl-for-use-in-visual-studio-2017) thread

For linux cmake you should add next to your cmake file

```
set(CURL_LIBRARY "-lcurl")
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
include_directories(... ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(... $(CURL_LIBRARIES))
```

Comment: oh im very gratfull tu u!! but could you show how to correctly add headers and the type of the request itself to the requests, since I frankly cannot understand how to do this correctly, because libcurl looks very difficult for me

Comment: @Leopold95 Can you please tell me on which operating system do you wish to do so? Ill write it down

Comment: now im under windows. But there is qt project in vs2019. maby in future ill to build this prog under linux

Comment: I editet answer with c++ cmake linux

Comment: For windows this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/54680718/9349507

Comment: ok.thx. but can u pls edit answer with adding my headers and request type (get, post etc)? i have no clue hoe to do this

Comment: @Leopold95 please wait a moment ill add it, but let me first test it

Comment: Oh. Ill be very grateful for u. But my my url wont wont work in any way. Because it need another host and bearer key

Comment: @Leopold95 yes, i see. Im just testing code.

Comment: @Leopold95 I added everything you need for starters, but you should read the curl documentation a bit to see what does what as you will need to modify this for your case

Comment: OMG  im very grateful for u!!! Thanks so much! Sry, but i cant taste this now. Ill answer u to the next day or maybe   in the evening but i will

Comment: so im vary gatefull u. everything works fine.